# How do I rotate a ModelMesh around its own axis?

Tags: matrix, xna, rotation, local, axis

I have a model of a car, the body is separate and the 4 tires are separate but they are in the same FBX file. I can rotate the car body and its working but the tire does not rotate around its own axis.

```
foreach (BasicEffect effect in carModel.Meshes[0].Effects) 
            { 
                effect.EnableDefaultLighting(); 
                effect.World = transforms[carModel.Meshes[0].ParentBone.Index] * carWorldMatrix; 
                effect.Projection = camera.projectionMatrix; 
                effect.View = camera.viewMatrix; 
            } 
            carModel.Meshes[0].Draw(); 

            foreach (BasicEffect effect in carModel.Meshes[1].Effects) 
            { 
                effect.EnableDefaultLighting(); 
                effect.World = transforms[carModel.Meshes[1].ParentBone.Index] * tireMatrix; 
                effect.Projection = camera.projectionMatrix; 
                effect.View = camera.viewMatrix; 
            } 
            carModel.Meshes[1].Draw();
```

To create the rotations I am just using Matrix.CreateRotationY(amount). How can I rotate the wheels on their own axis. I am just testing the 1 wheel right now, not all of them

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that your `tireMatrix` is the `Matrix.CreateRotationY(amount)` you mentioned. If so, you should implement it like this for drawing Meshes[1]:

```
effect.World = tireMatrix * transforms[carModel.Meshes[1].ParentBone.Index] * carWorld;
```

Comment: It does not work. The tire follows the car and rotates but not on its own axis, it rotates around the car.

Comment: That's probably because you chose Matrix.CreateRotationY instead of Maatrix.CreateRotationX ... or Z. Only you can tell what axis the wheel rotates around. I assumed you had with since you came up with the Y rotation

Comment: I kind of figured out the problem but I cannot solve it. The FBX file contains the car body and the 4 wheels. The wheels are placed where they suppose to be in the FBX file and in XNA they are drawn in their places and the car origin is also the origin of the wheels so when they rotate, they rotate around this origin. I manually tried figuring out where the origin of the car is by moving the vector of a wheel and to the centre, rotate the wheel and move it back to its place.

Answer (score 0):

I kind of figured out the problem but I cannot solve it. The FBX file contains the car body and the 4 wheels. The wheels are placed where they suppose to be in the FBX file and in XNA they are drawn in their places and the car origin is also the origin of the wheels so when they rotate, they rotate around this origin. I manually tried figuring out where the origin of the car is by moving the vector of a wheel and to the centre, rotate the wheel and move it back to its place. Like this

```
tireMatrix = Matrix.CreateTranslation(carOrigin) * 
             Matrix.CreateRotationY(rotAmount) * 
             Matrix.CreateTranslation(tirePos);
```

I first need to move the tire to the centre of the car, rotate it and translate it back to its position. Trying to figure out this manually is not giving me the exact location so is there a method of working out where the centre of the car is? using carMatrix.Translation just makes the tire rotate around the car and not its out place.